2 Ceiling Fans, 1 Switch. Series or Parallel?
I have two 70” Hunter ceiling fans I'm looking to install on the same wall switch indoors. The manufacturer has told me the fans are rated for doing so, though i am waiting to hear back from them to see if running them in series will cause any power issues if both fans run at full speed/brightness.
In an ideal world i would just wire this up in parallel, but i do not have access to the ceiling without ripping up a lot of drywall. My most realstic option is to slightly widen the existing hole of an old outlet box for an old ceiling fan, install a junction box, and split the wiring like in this post: Wiring a Junction Box: 1 source in, 2 sources out After this it’s a matter of cutting new holes in the ceiling and trying to feed the cables over without having to widen the hole much more than the 4-inches necessary for an outlet box.
Does this method create a series or parallel circuit? If a series, is there a relatively non-invasive way to wire up something like this in parallel without having direct access to the attic space?

You cannot put them in series.

How do you plan to use DC motors on an AC circuit?

@PeteBecker, why is that?

@RMDman they’re Hunter ceiling fans, the model is Loflin. I already have three of them installed elsewhere in the home running on the AC circuits. Haha

Your linked diagram shows parallel wiring. Both fans are controlled by a single switch as well as any switch on the fan itself when the main switch is on. Snarkiness is not well tolerated in this forum.

Thank you @DelphicOracle. I was not intending to sound snarky. Apologies I did come across that way.

Always Parallel
Keep in mind that parallel vs. series is at the individual wire electrical level. From a high-level physical cable view it may look series - switch -> fan -> fan, but really be parallel because of how the wires are connected at each fan.
Note that except for (a) equipment specifically designed for such installation and (b) simple resistive loads such as incandescent bulbs, parallel is almost always the correct answer for 120V or 240V devices. Even in the case of simple resistive loads where series may work OK, normal installation in most cases (e.g., multiple lights on one circuit) is parallel.
But this really shouldn't be a problem. There are really only four ways to wire up two fans:

Two cables from the switch box, one to each fan

This is really only ever parallel.

One cable from the switch box to the first fan, another cable from the first fan to the second fan

I suppose this could be in series. But it is just a matter of doing things correctly in the junction box above the first fan to make it parallel.

Incoming power to first fan box. Switch loop to switch box. Another cable to the second fan.

This also could be in series. But it is just a matter of doing things correctly in the junction box above the first fan to make it parallel.

Incoming power to first fan box. Another cable to the second fan. Switch loop from the second fan.

In this very specific case, it may be hard to do a parallel configuration. But it is worse than that, because I think you would end up with switched neutral (or at least switched neutral for the first fan) instead of switched hot. An overall mess. Unless the cable between the fans is a three-wire (black/white/red + ground) cable.
Note that all of this is about cables. If you have conduit then it is almost always possible to add additional wires to make things work properly, even in the final scenario I listed.

A little more explanation of series vs. parallel wiring methods.
Basic wiring has two wires (ignoring ground - ground is always there in modern AC wiring but all grounds are connected together and they just don't relate to this question). Let's call them L for Line/Load and N for Neutral.
In a parallel wiring setup you have L and N go to every device and pass along, unchanged (via a pigtail or two wires on a screw terminal or whatever), to the next device.
In a series wiring setup, L goes in to one device and the "output" of that device, instead of being N, is the L for the next device. While in theory (and in pure resistive loads that is basically the case) this should be OK, in practice it leads to a lot of problems with dimmer switches, motor controls and many types of devices.
Parallel
Panel (L) --> Switch (L) ----+----> ----+
                             |          |
                         Device 1   Device 2
                             |          |
Panel (N) <------------- <---+----- <---+

Series
Panel (L) --> Switch (L) --> Device 1 --> Device 2 --+
                                                     |
                                                     |
Panel (N) <------------------------------------------+

For reasons, L and N always need to be in the same cable or conduit, so in each case there are two wires in the cable or conduit. And that is really the key: the difference between series and parallel is in the connections at each device and not a different number or set or grouping of wires.
With the end result that parallel wiring is normally not a problem at all, including the installation of new devices as described in the question.

Thank you for your detailed explanation. It has been so many years since I used to fully understand series/parallel circuits without even having to think about it. Your post definitely clears a lot of it up at the conceptual level, I appreciate it greatly!

Another follow-up question, in the linked junction box example in my original post, and in what I’m suggesting for my case, is this an acceptable way to wire up both of the fans to the single switch? This method I’m visualizing is running the existing cable from the switch to a junction box, then running two new shorter cables from either end of that box to each of the fans. Inside the junction box the hots are connected to hots, neutrals to neutrals, and grounds to grounds all via wire nuts and secured with electrical tape.


Cutting new holes in the ceiling and trying to feed the cables over

So, fun fact:  Pulling cables has nothing to do with series/parallel wiring.
The parallel wiring technique for residential systems involves splicing all the wires of the branch circuit such that every load is connected to the same circuit breaker and every load is also connected to the same neutral path.  This all happens inside the junction boxes.
